Azure checklist file releated info is required
https://github.com/Azure/review-checklists/ - in this repo they are using json file and it contain GUID, Secure , Cost, Scale , Simple, HA.
{
            "category": "BC and DR",
            "subcategory": "Disaster Recovery",
            "text": "Schedule and perform DR tests regularly",
            "waf": "Reliability",
            "guid": "36cb45e5-7960-4332-9bdf-8cc23318da61",
            "id": "02.01.01",
            "ha": 1,
            "severity": "High",
            "link": "https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/enterprise-scale/business-continuity-and-disaster-recovery"
        }

Please expalin me how the Json file are made and how this value are defined.
I checked on the repo goto the script folder but no where it is mentioned how to get those value. I need to implement this on a azure project to check architect is being followed or not.

The guid: This is a unique identifier for the checklist item, which ensures that each identifier is unique.
According to this issue, it mentions that

At the top right of the checklist there are some green bar indicators. The AKS checklist has some additional metadata, that indicates whether a specific recommendation has a positive or negative impact in certain areas:


Resiliency (ha)
Cost (cost)
Simplicity (simple)
Security (secure)
Scalability (scale)


Fulfilling a recommendation that only has a positive impact on one dimension will not alter the indicators, but fulfilling (or not) a recommendation that has a positive impact on one dimension and a negative impact on another one will alter the indicators. For example, if I pick all of the security recommendations, some of them have a negative impact on simplicity, so my simplicity score will go down.
The weighted recommendations can be subjective, so the scores are just +1/-1, and the indicators are non-numerical.



Could you please explain to me how we are defining it. Is there any logic exist.

Hi @PranayaSwain, it is recommended to ask directly in this issue to get more accurate answers.
